# Navigation bar breaks grid on slides without navigation bar

Tags: beamer, navigation, grids

I have a problem with [beamer](/questions/tagged/beamer) as weird as the title suggests.

I defined two headline templates:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{nosections}{%
}
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{sections}{%
   \setbeamercolor*{headline}{bg=white,fg=tuddunkelgrau}%
   \hskip52mm%
   \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{0.5\paperwidth}{\hskip-8pt}{\hskip-8pt}
}
```

And I'm also using a the beamer grid

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}[grid][step=10mm]
```

to place some paths or arrows using tikz.

On slides with navigation bar the grid fits the tikz-coordinates, **but on slides without navigation bar, the grid has an offset of the height of the navigation bar.** If it would be the other way around, I could understand, but that way it does not make any sense to me. What goes wrong?

---

### Full MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{nosections}{%
}
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{sections}{%
   \setbeamercolor*{headline}{bg=white,fg=tuddunkelgrau}%
   \hskip52mm%
   \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{0.5\paperwidth}{\hskip-8pt}{\hskip-8pt}
}


\setbeamertemplate{background}[grid][step=10mm]

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}[nosections]    
\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={(current page.south west)},yscale=1]
    \draw[line width = 1pt] (5,5) -- (7,7); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I could work around it by defining an navigation bar with zero width for the template which is supposed to have no bar:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{nosections}{%
   \setbeamercolor*{headline}{bg=white,fg=tuddunkelgrau}%
   \hskip52mm%
   \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{0.5\paperwidth}{\hskip-8pt}{\hskip-8pt}
}
```

But that seems stupid to me, **what's the right way?**

PS: an alternative way of grid drawing is performance wise no option.

Comment: I think the problem is that `\pgfpointorigin`, which is used in the grid drawing, gets shifted, but don't know why....

Comment: As a workaround, it is enough to give the empty headline the same height `\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{nosections}{\vskip\headheight}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short workaround is to make the empty headline the same height as the normal one:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{nosections}{\vskip\headheight}
```

The underlying problem seems to be that `\pgfpointorigin` is shifted. It is used in the definition of the grid as the following:

```
\defbeamertemplate{background}{grid}[1][]
{%
  \setkeys{beamer@backgroundgrid}{step=0.5cm,color=fg!10!bg}%
  \setkeys{beamer@backgroundgrid}{#1}%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{\the\paperwidth}{\the\paperheight}
    \beamer@bggc
    \pgfpathgrid[stepx=\beamer@bggw,stepy=\beamer@bggw]{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\the\paperwidth}{\the\paperheight}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}
```

If this `pgfpicture` is replaced by `\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={(current page.south west)},yscale=1]`, then the grid is positioned according to the page.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{nosections}{\vskip0pt}
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{sections}{%
\setbeamercolor*{headline}{bg=white,fg=tuddunkelgrau}%
\hskip52mm%
\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{0.5\paperwidth}{\hskip-8pt}{\hskip-8pt}%
}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{background}{mygrid}[1][]
{%
    \setkeys{beamer@backgroundgrid}{step=0.5cm,color=fg!10!bg}%
    \setkeys{beamer@backgroundgrid}{#1}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={(current page.south west)},yscale=1]
        \beamer@bggc
        \pgfpathgrid[stepx=\beamer@bggw,stepy=\beamer@bggw]{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\the\paperwidth}{\the\paperheight}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{background}[mygrid][step=10mm]

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}[sections]    
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={(current page.south west)},yscale=1]
        \draw[line width = 1pt] (5,5) -- (7,7); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}[nosections]    
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={(current page.south west)},yscale=1]
        \draw[line width = 1pt] (5,5) -- (7,7); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It depends how "a little tweaked" will turn out performance-wise. There are various solutions out here using tikz, which are terribly slow. But they are also using loops, not in this case. I will try. But if the `\pgfpointorigin` is the reason, couldn't it just set to zero again?

Comment: I'm finally using another fix, which is inspired by your comment and your answer, so it would be nice if you include it to your answer, so I can accept it. The problem ist not `\pgfpointorigin` but the fact, that `\begin{pgfpicture}` refers to the `paperheight`, but it should refer to `paperheight-headheight`. So my final fix was: using the original template. but with `\begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{\the\paperwidth}{\the\paperheight-\headheight}`.In case you see a way to fix that without creating a new template, ot would be even better. I tought about redefining the paperheight, but got errors.

Comment: @thewaywewalk But with this approach the frames with headline are wrong, aren't they?

Comment: Damn yes, you're right. Then I use on of your other two suggestions. Preferably your comment as it is shorter, so maybe you want to add this to the answer.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I added it.